# Problem linking to a DLL from C++ console application

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I have a console application in C++. I need to access a functionality from a C++ DLL. How do I link the DLL from my console application?

Please help me in this regard.
Thanks,
Rakesh.

Comment: Usually, you just add the lib (you do have a .lib for your DLL, right?) to the linker command line (or, in Visual Studio, the input section of the linker).  Which compiler are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on whether you are using load-time or run-time dynamic linking.

With load-time dynamic linking, you simply link against the import library for the DLL and make sure the DLL is in [the right location](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682586%28VS.85%29.aspx) when you run.  With run-time dynamic linking, you need to use `LoadLibrary` and `GetProcAddress` to make calls into the DLL.

[Both are described in detail on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686912%28VS.85%29.aspx), with examples.

Comment: Here is one more simple tutorial: http://www.infernodevelopment.com/how-create-dll-c-using-run-time-dynamic-linking

Comment: Chek this out [DLL Tutorial For Beginners](http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/cpp/cpp_mfc/tutorials/article.php/c9855)